# Why is theme.inc looking for view template in calendar module

Tags: views, theming, datetime

So I am working on updating a drupal site that was very out of date, I have updated everything to the latest versions. When I updated the Calendar module things started going awry, now most of my views don't display anything. I'm assuming this error is the reason:

```
Warning: include(__custom_path__/sites/all/modules/calendar/views-view-fields.tpl.php): failed to open stream: No such file or directory in theme_render_template() (line 1525 of __custom_path__/includes/theme.inc).
```

I've searched and while there are numerous potential fixes none have worked. The last one I tried, adding a empty version of the *views-view-fields.tpl.php* and that only creates a different error where theme.inc can't find *calendar.views.inc* because it look for it at the path *calendar/calendar.views.inc* instead of *calendar/includes/calendar.views.inc*

Why is it looking for this in calendar instead of views? What can I do to fix this?

Comment: Did you try registry_rebuild https://www.drupal.org/project/registry_rebuild and of course cache clear? Also could you tell from what version to what version you updated?

Comment: When running registry_rebuild form drush this is the output:
The registry has been rebuilt via registry_rebuild (A).              [success]
include_once(__custom_path__sites/all/modules/calendar/calendar.views.inc):[warning]
failed to open stream: No such file or directory theme.inc:565
include_once(): Failed opening                                       [warning]
'__custom_path__/sites/all/modules/calendar/calendar.views.inc'
for inclusion (include_path='.:') theme.inc:565
All caches have been cleared with...

Comment: for the calendar module it was 7.x-2.x-dev -> 7.x-3.5
The registry rebuild nor cache clear affected anything.

Comment: can you revert back?  maybe try updgrading one version at a time, rather than such a large leap - there could be DB adjustments not being done properly because the range of versions

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I cannot reproduce this myself but take a look at

https://www.drupal.org/node/1091376

It is an old ticket but is for the  7.x-2.x-dev branch and basicly it says disable your module remove the module directory and reinstall it so something like

Will disable the module.

```
 drush dis calendar
```

Will uninstall the module (if the module has a uninstall hook)

```
drush pmu calendar
```

Remove the directory

```
rm -rf __custom_path__/sites/all/modules/calendar
```

Most likely not necessary but wont hurt but will rebuild the registry and clear all cache

```
drush rr
drush cc all
```

Download the newest version of the module

```
drush dl calendar
```

And enable it.

```
drush en calendar
```

It should remove all traces of the old calendar and add a clean copy/install.

I would also do a drush updatedb just to double check if after all that everything is still in order.

Comment: Thanks for the clear instructions on this. I'm a little weak in the drupal admin dept. but this worked perfectly.